# How clicking on product will show animation to open a door and zoom in to the specific product on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

When a user clicking on the product from bottom bar, then the Door Will open and specific product display on the shop showcase Which will zoom in with details. How to do that on canvas?
Here is the actual image for the product select and showcasing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfajh.png)

Comment: You'd split the moving parts of the image into separate sprites, draw them on the canvas and animate them how you like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.